# How to repeat data in nested ul li ul li list item in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a new `ul>li>ul>li` list and I want to repeat the data according to the list items.

My code is like this:

[image: Screenshot]

**My Angular code is:**

```
var myAppMy = angular.module('myFapp', []);
myAppMy.controller('myControler', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        title:"book" [
          {subtitle:"name", description:"____Book_______"}
          ],
        description: "Some Book is very Good."
      }, 
      {
        title:"book_2" [
          {subtitle:"name", description:"____Book_2______"}
          ],
        description: "2Some Book is very Good."
      }
    ];
});
```

**My HTML code is:**

```
<body ng-app="myFapp">
    <ul ng-controller="myControler">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div>{{item.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item.description}}</div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>{{subtitle.title}}</div>
                    <div>{{item.description}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9p4YR0ONhfnw8nU4Vvde?p=preview)**

Comment: I m repeat a data in listed item as like this ul > li >ul > li in nested child

Comment: Invalid JSON `title:"book"[{subtitle:"name",description:"____Book_______"}]`, this will create null/unidentified field

Comment: as like this http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/files/2013/12/image_thumb95.png

Comment: your json is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is improper, It needs to be in this format:

JSON:

```
$scope.items = [
      {
        "title":"book" ,"subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"name", "description":"____Book_______"}
          ],
        "description": "Some Book is very Good."
      }, 
      {
        "title":"book_2" , "subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"name", "description":"____Book_2______"}
          ],
        "description": "2Some Book is very Good."
      }

    ];
```

And then in your html markup you need to reference it like this (nested ng-repeat):

```
    <ul ng-controller="myControler">
        <li ng-repeat= "item in items">
          <div>{{item.title}} </div>
          <div>{{item.description}}</div>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subtitle in item.subtitle">
              <div>{{subtitle.subtitle}} </div>
              <div>{{subtitle.description}}</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xa6mt52XPLJSQBSAubSJ?p=preview)